# the_content() keeps repeating itself

Tags: loop, the-content

I'm new to Wordpress and am having trouble getting my loop to make the_content() not repeat itself. I've tried writing multiple loops as well to no avail. I mainly just want the_content() to iterate inside of the reveal modal.

```
 <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'c3k_project', 'posts_per_page' => 8 ) ); ?>
  <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<div class="grid-item">
  <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">
    <figure class="text-overlay">
      <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>">
      <?php endif; ?>
      <figcaption>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <?php the_author(); ?>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal full chicken-modal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-12 columns">

      <?php the_content(); ?>

    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
</div>

  <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. This was due to reveal using an ID (see myModal ID) and iterating the same ID over and over again. As a fix, I used:

```
id="modal-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"
```

This has solved my issue of the_content() repeating its first iteration over and over.